# Make Bootstrap Dropdown menu bigger

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the right way to make the menu drop down bigger  in bootstrap? I have tried adding divider class and hr, but it doesn't look right. Here is the link to the code I've tried so far [Bootstrap Drop down menu](http://www.bootply.com/a1aaQaFRWE)

Comment: Bigger in terms of width or height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the CSS. Try overriding the CSS on `.dropdown-menu>li>a` like below:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a { padding:15px 25px; }
```

The easiest way to know which one to modify is to inspect element using Google Chrome's (Shortcut = F12) or Firefox's FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu{
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

Adjust the padding to this element as you see fit but just make sure to load this css after you load bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the css is not easy when you use the integrated stylesheet, You can add extra style's like `padding:15px 25px` in the `ul`class from the dropbox. See the example below:

```
<ul style="padding:15px 25px" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
```

I hope this will help! Good luck